# How to configure Apache NIFI with ssl enabled on google cloud to connect with https load balancer health check

Tags: ssl, https, google-cloud-platform, apache-nifi, tls1.2

I have installed apache nifi with ambari (Versions: Nifi 1.9.0, AMBARI 2.7.3, HDF 3.4.1.1-4) on google cloud. There is an https load balancer in front of a three node instance group. The front end terminates in https, using the standard google supplied let's encrypt certificate. The backend end is https, pointing at the port on the three node instance group where nifi is listening, with ssl enabled. Before enabling ssl, I was able to connect to the http nifi on the backend. With ssl enabled, a tcpdump reveals a Bad Certificate error in the tls handshake between the respective nifi nodes and the load balancer health check IP range.

I am looking for how to configure nifi so that nifi sends the entire chain of certificates and completes a successful handshake with the health check.

Right now my nifi ssl config node entities are:
CN=full qualified domain name (FQDN)of node 1, OU=NIFI</property>
CN=full qualified domain name (FQDN)of node 2, OU=NIFI</property>
CN=full qualified domain name (FQDN)of node 3, OU=NIFI</property>
-->

I have created and downloaded certs from TinyCert, and generated the keystore.jks and truststore.jks files which are on each nifi node.

The keystore contains two entries:

Alias name: cert
        Creation date: Oct 31, 2019
        Entry type: trustedCertEntry
        Owner: CN=FQDN of node 1, OU=NIFI, O=Staq, L=Baltimore, ST=Md, C=US
        Issuer: CN=Staq CA, OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing, O=Staq, L=Baltimore, ST=Md, C=US

```
    Alias name: cacert
    Creation date: Oct 31, 2019
    Entry type: trustedCertEntry
    Owner: CN=Staq CA, OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing, O=Staq, L=Baltimore, ST=Md, C=US
    Issuer: CN=Staq CA, OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing, O=Staq, L=Baltimore, ST=Md, C=US
```

How do I make the health check successfully make the tls handshake with the nifi node ?

```
The Google load balancer back end is an instance group with three nodes, nifi1, nifi2, nifi3, where nifi is running on each and listening on port 9091. 
The backend service is protocol https, named port https, the instance group is entered for the backend and port number is 9091. 
When I sit on nifi1 and curl the internal ip:9091 of nifi2, in a tcpdump of eth0 activity , I get a fatal error 'Unknown CA' in the handshake from nifi1 to nifi2. In the same tcpdump I see the healch check trying to connect to nifi2 ip:9091, from the range of IP addresses health check uses, and it gets a fatal error during the tls handshake, 'Bad Certificate'.  

I went to TinyCert.org, and created a certificate for each node, so the CN for each node is the FQDN(fully qualified domain name) , the OU is NIFI, and the rest of the fields are the same. The Certificate Authority CN is Staq CA, the OU is 'Secure Digital Certificate Signing', and the rest of the fields are the same. So I have a cacert.pem , and each node has a set of files: 
certchain.pfx,
cert.pfx,
key.dec.pem, 
key.enc.pem, 
certchin.pem, 
and cert.pem.

    openssl verify -CAfile ../cacert.pem cert.pem 
    cert.pem: OK

For NIFI, I generated a keystore.jks and a truststore.jks file, and loaded these to /etc/security/nifi-certs,  and put this location in the 
nifi.properties file. 
                nifi.web.http.host=
                nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=
                nifi.web.http.port=
                nifi.web.https.host=FQDN (same as used in CN name) 
                nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
                nifi.web.https.port=9091


The login-identity-providers.xml is empty. 

I used the following to create the truststore and keystore.

    openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.enc.pem -out abc.pkcs12 

    Enter pass phrase for key.enc.pem:    PASSPHR
    Enter Export Password:                PASSWD

    keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore abc.pkcs12 -srcstoretype 
    PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype jks 
    Importing keystore abc.pkcs12 to keystore.jks...
    Enter destination keystore password:  PASSWD
    Re-enter new password:                PASSWD
    Enter source keystore password:       PASSWD
    Entry for alias 1 successfully imported.

    keytool -import -file ../cacert.pem -alias cacert -keystore 
    truststore.jks -storepass 
    trust this certficate: yes
```

Comment: Google Cloud HTTP Load Balancers support self-signed certificates installed on backends. What is the expiration date for the certificate? Did you install the certificate, certificate chain, and private key correctly? I think your problem is the certificate chain. Verify by directly connecting to a backend with `curl` or a similar tool. Also, edit your question with details on how the health check is configured.

Comment: Reread my comment. Then use a tool like `curl` to verify the backend is working. Use `openssl` to verify that the certificate and certificate chain are correct. In your latest edit, I do not see where you have done anything with the intermediate certificate chain. For self-signed certificates, you must provide the private key, the certificate, and the certificate chain. Often you can combine the certificate and the intermediate chain into one file (append the chain to the certificate file).

Comment: For self-signed certificates, nothing cares about the FQDN. You are analyzing the wrong area.

Comment: ran the following but still getting untrusted CA errors:

Comment: openssl pkcs12 -in certchain.pfx -out certchain.pem 
cat certchain.pem >>  cert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.enc.pem -out abcchain.pkcs12
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore abcchain.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype jks

Comment: Certificate chain length: 2  - this was length of 1 before using the certchain.pfx file. The certchain.pfx file was one of original files downloaded from TinyCert.org

Comment: Use `openssl` to connect to your site and not to test files. The files do not matter. It is what is setup in your backend that needs to be tested.

Comment: actually reviewing the tcpdump with wireshark, it looks like the the tls message for nifi1 to nifi2 is Certificate Verify , no bad certificate error - the handshake with the backend health check IP is getting the bad certificate.